# How to include javascript in cakephp 1.3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

Wait moment this question not duplicated..it is sample and difficult at the same time.

This simple problem make me crazy..

```
http://www.mediafire.com/?2vi2kc7tpqiw1to
```

This is slide code contain CSS, HTML, jQuery code.

This slide works fine, but when I include this slide in cakephp it is not
working.

I put jQuery files and CSS in webroot and put the code to include in
layout/default.ctp like this

```
echo $javascript->link('jcookie.js');
echo $javascript->link('jquery-1.3.2.min.js');
echo $javascript->link('jcarousellite.js');
echo $javascript->link('jquery-1.js');
```

but still nothing happen ..please anyone help me..download the slide and try to click on the top to slideshow pictures..and then include it in cake..you will find the problem..

Comment: You can try passing an array into `$javascript->link` instead, like `$javascript->link(array('jcookie.js', 'jquery-1.3.2.min.js', 'jcarousellite.js', 'jquery-1.js'));` - not sure how that will help, but I suppose it's better than nothing.

Comment: i tried this sulution john but slide not work..thank you

Comment: please tag ur questions correctly. this not a cakephp 2.0 question

Answer (score 1):

a) you shouldnt use $javascript anymore. it would be $this->Javascript

b) javascript itself is deprecated (see the documentation)

so use

```
$this->Html->script()
```

details:
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1589/script

Comment: thank you mark..i tried all ways and your suggestion but the slide not work also

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get e Jquery Slider working on a Cake generated page default.ctp:

I dropped my js files in webroot/js/libs and css files in webroot/css - NOTE: That the .js and .css extensions are left off.

```
<?php
 echo $this->Html->css('royalslider', null, array('inline' => true));
 echo $this->Html->css('royalslider-skins/default/default', null, array('inline' => true);
 echo $this->Javascript->link('libs/jquery-1.6.2.min', true);
 echo $this->Javascript->link('libs/jquery.easing.1.3.min', true);
 echo $this->Javascript->link('libs/royal-slider-7.9.min', true);
 echo $scripts_for_layout;
endif;
?>
```

I put the slider HTML somewhere in the body

I put the Slider Javascript: 
    script type="text/javascript" right before the closing /body tag..