# CakePHP 1.3 Html helper - undefined property error

Tags: jquery, cakephp, undefined, cakephp-1.3, helper

I'm using cakePHP 1.3 and have problems with the html-helper.

I want to use autocomplete and therefore I need to load the html-helper in the head of my view (i.g. to load the css). First I followed this tutorial: [JQuery autocomplete in CakePHP](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/05/07/jquery-autocomplete-in-cakephp/)

but there was the same problem with javascript as it is now with html. Then I tried the new version of the tutorial: [CakePHP and jQuery auto-complete revisited](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2013/08/27/cakephp-and-jquery-auto-complete-revisited/)

I know the new tutorial was written for CakePHP 2.3 but I read that the functionality for jQuery should be the same for CakePHP 1.3.

So the header of my view looks like this:

```
<?php
  echo $this->Html->css('https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'); ?>
```

But this throws the following error:

> Notice (8): Undefined property: View::$Html
>   [APP\views\produkt\show.ctp, line 5] Fatal error: Call to a member
>   function css() on a non-object

In any case (css, jquery, ...) this error occurs. So it seems to me that the problem belongs to the helper. Also if I use the script-method.

The html-helper exists in my cake/libs/views/helpers folder. Also I load it in the produkt_controller:

```
class ProduktController extends AppController {
var $helpers = array (
        'Html',
        'Check',
        'Misc'
);
```

I have already searched here for a solution, but found no answer that fits for me. Sadly the link to cakePHP mentioned in this post [how to include javascript in cakephp 1.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191877/how-to-include-javascript-in-cakephp-1-3)  is somehow broken and I didn't found an answer to my problem in the cookbook for cakePHP 1.3.

Please, if someone could help me to get the helper running, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 1.3 it is

```
$html->methodName()
```

while in 2.0 it became

```
$this->Html->methodName()
```

Why are you reading the documentation for 2.0? [The documentation for 1.3 is still up](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/).

Comment: Although I read the documentation for 1.3, I overlooked that, don't know why... now it works! Thanks!